# How to use Animated vector drawable in Compose

Tags: android, android-jetpack-compose, android-drawable, android-image, android-vectordrawable

I created my vector drawable animation and I want to use in in Compose. I found in [official documentation](https://developer.android.com/jetpack/compose/resources) that I need to call `animatedVectorResource`. But whole `AnimatedImageVector` has been removed from compose till next versions. How to launch animated drawable in current compose version?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to update compose to `1.1.0-alpha01` and add the module `androidx.compose.animation:animation-graphics` as indicated in the last changelog

[image]

```kotlin
implementation("androidx.compose.animation:animation-graphics:1.1.0-alpha01")
```

```kotlin
val image = animatedVectorResource(id = R.drawable.animated_vector)
val atEnd by remember { mutableStateOf(false) }
Icon(
   painter = image.painterFor(atEnd = atEnd),
   contentDescription = null
)
```

Comment: I need something like this https://developer.android.com/reference/androidx/vectordrawable/graphics/drawable/SeekableAnimatedVectorDrawable but for compose?

Answer (score 4):

Updated answer: [Reference](https://developer.android.com/reference/kotlin/androidx/compose/animation/graphics/res/package-summary#rememberAnimatedVectorPainter(androidx.compose.animation.graphics.vector.AnimatedImageVector,kotlin.Boolean))

```
implementation("androidx.compose.animation:animation-graphics:1.3.3")

var atEnd by remember { mutableStateOf(false) }
val drawable = AnimatedImageVector.animatedVectorResource(R.drawable.avd_anim)

IconButton(onClick = { atEnd = !atEnd }) {
   Icon(
      painter = rememberAnimatedVectorPainter(animatedImageVector = drawable, atEnd = atEnd),
      contentDescription = null
   )
}
```

Answer (score 3):

`AnimatedImageVector` was temporarily [removed](https://developer.android.com/jetpack/androidx/releases/compose-ui#1.0.0-rc01) in `1.0.0-rc01` and it is not present in the final stable `1.0.0`.

Starting from `1.1.0-alpha01` `AnimatedImageVector` and the related APIs are now in the new
`androidx.compose.animation:animation-graphics` module.

You can use something like:

```
    val image = AnimatedImageVector.animatedVectorResource(drawableId)
    var atEnd by remember { mutableStateOf(false) }
    Image(
        painter = image.painterFor(atEnd),
        contentDescription = "Your content description",
        modifier = Modifier.size(64.dp).clickable {
            atEnd = !atEnd
        }
    )
```